# Fundamental solution of heat equation: Show $\lvert v(x,t)-v(x,t')\rvert\leq \left\lVert\frac{d^2}{dx^2}u_0\right\rVert_{L^\infty}\lvert t-t'\rvert$

Tags: real-analysis, estimation, heat-equation

Let
$$
v(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{4\pi t}}\int_\mathbb{R} e^{-(x-y)^2/(4t)}u_0(y)\, dy
$$
be the fundamental solution of the heat equation.

Would like to prove that
$$
\lvert v(x,t)-v(x,t')\rvert\leq \left\lVert\frac{d^2}{dx^2}u_0\right\rVert_{L^\infty}\lvert t-t'\rvert.
$$

---

The only way I see is to use integration by parts.

Substituting $z=\frac{y-x}{2\sqrt{t}}$, I get

$$
v(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_\mathbb{R}e^{-z^2} u_0(2\sqrt{t}z+x)\, dz
$$

Integrating by parts twice gives me
$$
v(x,t)=\left[\frac{\textrm{erf}(z)}{2}\cdot u_0(2\sqrt{t}z+x)\right]_{-\infty}^\infty - \sqrt{t}\left[\left(z\cdot\textrm{erf}(z)+\frac{e^{-z^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\right)\cdot u_0'(2\sqrt{t}z+x)\right]_{-\infty}^\infty+2t\int_\mathbb{R} \left(z\cdot\textrm{erf}(z)+\frac{e^{-z^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\right)u_0''(2\sqrt{t}z+x)\, dz
$$
and, analogously,
$$
v(x,t')=\left[\frac{\textrm{erf}(z)}{2}\cdot u_0(2\sqrt{t'}z+x)\right]_{-\infty}^\infty - \sqrt{t'}\left[\left(z\cdot\textrm{erf}(z)+\frac{e^{-z^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\right)\cdot u_0'(2\sqrt{t'}z+x)\right]_{-\infty}^\infty+2t'\int_\mathbb{R} \left(z\cdot\textrm{erf}(z)+\frac{e^{-z^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}\right)u_0''(2\sqrt{t'}z+x)\, dz
$$

Looks terrible. However, can one use this to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried to go through the entire argument myself, but have you considered using the fact that

$$|v(x, t)- v(x, t')| = |\int_{t'}^t v_{\tau}(x, \tau) \, d \tau| = |\int_{t'}^t v_{xx} (x, \tau) \, d \tau| \leq \lVert v_{xx}(x, \tau) \rVert_{\infty} |t-t'|$$

and try to relate $\lVert v_{xx}(x, \tau) \rVert_{\infty}$ to $\lVert u_0 ''(x) \rVert_{\infty}$?

Comment: That's a very nice idea. I did not try this. The only thing I know is that for any $\tau>0$ there exists $C>0$ such that $\lvert v_{xx}(x,\tau)\rvert\leq \frac{C}{\tau}\lVert u_0\rVert_{L^\infty}$.

Comment: Maybe one further comment: The original aim is to show that $v$ is Lipschitz in $t$. In order to prove this, I think $$\lvert v(x,t)-v(x,t')\rvert\leq\lVert v_{xx}(x,\tau)\rVert_\infty \lvert t-t'\rvert$$ is totally enough, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that suffices to show Lipschitz continuity, in which case the Lipschitz constant you have found is $\lVert v_{xx}(x, \tau) \rVert_{\infty}$.

Comment: Then, I think that it was maybe a typo and it was meant the second spatial derivative of $v$ instad of the second derivative of $u_0$.